# Difficult Calculus Question (Differentiation)

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I stumbled across this question in my maths textbook and have no idea how to solve it. I have looked at the answers and don't understand how to get it from the question. It's in the chapter titled 'The Quotient Rule' but am not sure how to apply it to this question:

Find the normal to the curve $x = \frac{t}{t+1}$ and $y = \frac{t}{t-1}$ at the point T where t = 2.

I tried converting this into one equation ($y = \frac{x(t+1)}{t-1}$) but don't see how to get the answer which says:

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{-(t+1)^2}{(t-1)^2}$$

and that $ T = (\frac23,2)$, $3x - 27y + 52 = 0$

I'd appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that the chain rule gives $\frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{dy}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}$. So as long as $\frac{dx}{dt} \neq 0$, we can solve for $\frac{dy}{dx}$, yielding the equation:

$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy/dt}{dx/dt}$

This should give you the slope of the tangent line to the parametric curve you specified.

Comment: And I am guessing the Quotient Rule falls into place when finding $\frac{dx}{dt}$ and $\frac{dy}{dt}$. Thank you

Comment: @Monacraft Yup, you're correct. If you like to find the second derivative of $y$ with respect to $x$, the same idea holds above.

Answer (score 0):

We have: $\dfrac{t+1}{t} = \dfrac{1}{x} \Rightarrow 1+\dfrac{1}{t} = \dfrac{1}{x}$. Similarly, $\dfrac{t-1}{t} = \dfrac{1}{y} \Rightarrow 1-\dfrac{1}{t} = \dfrac{1}{y}$. Add the $2$ equations to get: $2=\dfrac{1}{x}+\dfrac{1}{y} \Rightarrow y = \dfrac{x}{2x-1}$. From this you can directly find $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$,and to completely answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$x = \frac{t}{t+1}$ and $y = \frac{t}{t-1}$

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{t+1-t}{(t+1)^2}=\frac{1}{(t+1)^2}$$

$$\frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{t-1-t}{(t-1)^2}=\frac{-1}{(t-1)^2}$$

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\frac{dy}{dt}}{\frac{dx}{dt}}=\frac{-(t+1)^2}{(t-1)^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if this working isn't top notch, but I'm only a 16 year old student! It's a bit late too as this is the first time I've used LaTeX!

By, the quotient rule, we have:
$$\frac{\text{d}x}{\text{d}t}=\frac{1(t+1)-t(1)}{(t+1)^{2}}=\frac{-1}{(t-1)^{2}}$$
$$\frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}t}=\frac{1(t-1)-t(1)}{(t-1)^{2}}=\frac{-1}{(t-1)^{2}}$$

By the chain rule:
$$\frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}x}=\frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}t}\cdot\frac{\text{d}t}{\text{d}x}$$
$$\therefore\frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}x}=\frac{-1}{(t-1)^{2}}\cdot\frac{(t+1)^{2}}{1}$$
$$\Rightarrow\frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}x}=\frac{-(t+1)^{2}}{(t-1)^{2}}$$

Answer (score 0):

X= t/(t+1) 
Y= t/(t-1)

dx/dt = (t+1)-t / (t+1)²

dx/dt= 1/(t+1)²

dy/dt = (t-1)-t/(t-1)²

dy/dt= -1/(t-1)²

dy/dx = dy/dt × dt/dx

note, dt/dx is d inverse of dx/dt

So, 
dy/dx = -1/(t-1)² × (t+1)²

dy/dx = -(t+1)²/(t-1)²

When t= 2,

dy/dx = -(2+1)²/(2-1)²

dy/dx = -9

Note, dy/dx = gradient = m

So,

m = -9

Gradient of normal
m'= -1/m

So, 
m' = -1/-9

m'= 1/9

Equation of normal =

Y-y = (X-x)m'
Recall,  x= t/(t+1)

y= t /(t-1)

Since t =2

Substitute for t

x= 2/2+1
x=2/3

y=2/2-1
y=2

Back to the equation of normal

Substitute for x and y and m'

Y-2 = (X-⅔)×1/9

Y-2=X/9 - 2/27

Y-2=(3X-2)/27

27(Y-2) = 3X-2

27Y-54=3X-2

27Y=3X+52

SOLVED

Comment: See this [brief introduction to posting mathematical notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).  There are also links there to more detailed examples and explanations.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a question of [Parametric derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_derivative#:%7E:text=In%20calculus%2C%20a%20parametric%20derivative,by%20parametric%20equations%20in%20t).
$$(x,y)=\left(\frac{t}{t+1},\frac{t}{t-1}\right)$$
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{d(t(t+1)^{-1})}{dt}=t(-1)(t+1)^{-2}+(t+1)^{-1}=\frac{-t}{(t+1)^2}+\frac{1}{(t+1)^2}$$
Similarly,
$$\frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{d(t(t-1)^{-1})}{dt}=\frac{-t}{(t-1)^2}+\frac{1}{t-1}$$
Therefore,$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\frac{-t}{(t-1)^2}+\frac{1}{t-1}}{\frac{-t}{(t+1)^2}+\frac{1}{t+1}}=\frac{-t+t-1}{(t-1)^2}\times \frac{(t+1)^2}{-t+t+1}=-\left(\frac{t+1}{t-1}\right)^2$$
This is the slope of the tangent.

The slope of the normal is $\left(\frac{t-1}{t+1}\right)^2$. Since $t=2$, therefore the slope of normal is $\frac{1}{9}$.

Coordinates of point $T=\left(\frac{2}{2+1},\frac{2}{2-1}\right)=\left(\frac{2}{3},2\right)$

So, the equation of normal is $y=\frac{1}{9}x+c$. Since normal passes through the point T, therefore,
$$2=\frac{1}{9}\times \frac{2}{3}+c \implies c=\frac{52}{27}$$
Therefore the equation of normal is $y=\frac{1}{9}x+\frac{52}{27}\implies 3x-27y+52=0$.